# How to cast a pointer to member of base class to a pointer to the same member of derived class

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member

Consider the following example :

```
struct foo {
    int bax;
};

struct fuu : foo {
};

template<int foo::*>
struct tox {};

template<int fuu::*>
struct tux {};

int foo::* xo = &foo::bax;
int fuu::* xu = &fuu::bax;   // works

typedef int foo::*boz;

typedef tox<&foo::bax> qox;
typedef tux<&fuu::bax> qux; // fails: 'int foo::*' cannot be converted to a value of type 'int fuu::*'
typedef tux<(boz)&fuu::bax> qux; // fails: non-type template argument of type 'boz' (aka 'int foo::*') cannot be converted to a value of type 'int fuu::*'
```

This example is also available on http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15f3e7acd8de04a3 , Both clang++ and g++ produce the same error.

How to cast fuu::bax so it is accepted by template tux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there's any way to do this yet. There is an [open defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#440) about this issue. You will have to work around it somehow, such as changing `tux` so it accepts `int foo::*` instead, or adding another template parameter:

```
template <typename T, int T::* arg>
struct tux {
    static_assert(std::is_convertible<int T::*, int fuu::*>::value,
                  "T must be an unambiguous accessible base of fuu");
    // note that this still works
    // however, you won't be able to use it as a template argument
    static constexpr int fuu::* pm = arg;
};
```